# Flutter and Android files

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

I've using VSCODE for Flutter and android studio for Android codes, but i dont want to use two ide at the same time, since i can't juggle with ides...

If i open Flutter project android studio doesn't complain anything, But if I open file.kt files then android studio complains about SDK was not setup, after that i setup SDK for android, Android studio started complain about .kt files.

It's really annoying, Is there any way i can use Single IDE for both of the codes?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "complain"? What is the error message?

Comment: if the android project successfully running on android studio that means other tools necessary for android projects are successfully configured by android studio. Now you can just uninstall android studio then use VSCode with flutter plugin.

Comment: Everything about .kt files the imports are cranky and it doesn't work with .kt files anymore, except the flutter dart files.